# Cannot install spotify

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, spotify

I'm having problems installing the spotify client on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed the latest updates, but it didn't change anything.

First I ran:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```

After that I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

But it says

```
cannot find package spotify-client...
```

Comment: Great question, nicely written, but you know the spotify client is just a beta. That isn't that well taken care of.

Comment: What did you with `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`? Ran in terminal?

Comment: it's almost as polished as the web player. But at least it works, and yes I use it on my laptop :)

Comment: Are you doing this through a LiveUSB? I found that spotify does not install properly on a LiveUSB.

Answer (score 2):

I found the 32bit version of Spotify, here's the link:
http://spotify.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/download/78109

Then open terminal and go to the directory the file has been downloaded to and run:

```
dpkg -i spotify-0-9-4-183-en-ubu.deb
```

Spotify now works on my system, running on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the server address to your server list.
Like this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
```

Simply running `deb "source"` wont add it to you list which is where all apt commands are looking. So of course it won't find anything. :)

Comment: it's still not working. I'm using the 32bit version of Ubuntu does that matter?

Comment: @JensVDE Yeah, that's the problem there's only a 64-bit version available. Why aren't you running 64-bit? it can run on only 2GB of RAM...

Comment: Well Spotify is installed on my other laptop and that runs the 32bit version of Ubuntu 12.04. I installed Spotify a long time ago on that one. Maybe I can download an older version of Spotify with 32bit support?

Comment: if it's still available. What I know it was gone around December 2014, so t's unlikely to find it... And if you find it somewhere else, are you sure you will trust it?

Comment: I didn't read the part about the 2gb ram. Well I have 2gb of ram and I'm not planning on upgrading my pc. So I thought the 32bit version was going to be more compactible with older applications than the 64bit version... But I guess that isn't true

Comment: @JensVDE well 64-bit is 100% backward compatible :), well now you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You typed `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free` as a command, instead of adding it to your /etc/sources. Instead, type the following commands in order.

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Comment: it's still not working. I'm using the 32bit version of Ubuntu does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify doesn't have support to 32bit CPUs from now (may-2015) for install it in a 32bit CPU u should do it manually with dpkg as they have said.